# SubmitAdapterAuthentication() getting timeout but not getting caught

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Worklight 6.2 for my application and it has adapter-based authentication.

I am using the `SubmitAdapterAuthentication()` function for authenticating the user and there is correct implementation for `isCustomResponse` and `handleChallenge` functions.

The issue is, if the WL Server is not reachable and the request timeouts, the console immediately says that the REQUEST TIMEOUT happened but the same is not caught on the application to indicate to the user.

While doing an `invokeProcedure()`, this is never an issue as the `onFailure` function handles the timeout.

Am I missing something in this?

**UPDATE :**

From login button `onClick()` we are calling the `SubmitAdapterAuthentication()` function.

When we get a response from worklight server, it is parsed through the `isCustomResponse()` function and that is further handled by `handleChallenge()`.

But in case of a Request-timout, none of the functions handle that response and as a result, we cannot determine when the timeout happened.

Is there a way to check timeout event when using `SubmitAdapterAuthentication()` ?

Thanks,
Vishal

Comment: I think you need to provide some code samples. *Exactly* how are you setting up the challenge handler?

Answer (score 0):

What are you sending as part of the `submitAdaterAuthentication()` function? This function accepts a standards options object, meaning `onSuccess` and `onFailure`.

So the question is if you have implemented the `onFailure`, because in case of a request timeout the `onFailure` callback function should then be called.

Additionally I would make sure that you did not place a securityTest on the your submit authentication adapter procedure.

Comment: There is no securityTest on the login function.

Comment: Hi @Idan, we are using Javascript apis for this as the app is hybrid app and there is no mention of onSuccess and onFailure in the documentation.

Comment: There is. It says is uses a standard options object and if you will search for "standard options object" you will see it lists what I mention.

Comment: It is not mentioned for JavaScript api

Comment: Please use Google next time: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/apiref/r_the_options_object.html

Comment: I came to SO only  after googling the issue.
I saw this link - https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.AbstractChallengeHandler.html?cp=SSHS8R_7.0.0%2F9-0-0-1-8&lang=en

Comment: It says -
submitAdapterAuthentication
submitAdapterAuthentication(invocationData, options)
Used to send collected credentials to a specific adapter procedure. It has the same signature as the WL.Client.invokeProcedure() function.
Parameters:
invocationData - Mandatory. A JSON block of parameters. 
{
adapter : adapter-name.wlname,
procedure : adapter-name.procedure-name.wlname,
parameters : [],
}
options - Optional. Parameters hash.

It does not say to use the standard options object

Comment: Fine. It doesn't. Did you try?

Comment: Yes, i was previously passing {} for options which i replaced with a JS object with onSuccess and onFailure functions, but nothing is fired.

Comment: Hi Idan, any comments?